# How to resolve these JAVA_HOME path error in contiki-ng cooja

Tags: java, gcc, contiki, cooja

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ant run
We cannot run Java, please ensure you have Java installed.
We have tried to execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java but failed.
If you have installed Java in a unusual place you can set JAVA_HOME
to the directory containing the Java installation.

Kindly help me to how to resolve the java path setting error.

Comment: Please post output of `readlink -f "$(which java)"`